# Is it possible to turn this request into an API?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to call an external REST API (dynamical URL) through a parameter in express and turn that into an API for my site(most of these APIs require being run on the web server, and won't run on the client). However, I'm not sure how exactly to go about combining this? I've been searching around on SO, but most solutions come to no success for me. I'm trying basically to:
Retrieve link from front end -> use the link to get info from API -> to use my own /getInfo API to send the data I retrieved back.

Snippet:

```
app.get('/api/getInfo/', (req,res) => {
    const info = req.query.url;
    res.send(getRest(info));
    
})

function getRest(url) {
Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
})
}
```

I'm calling it on my frontend via this method:

```
const GET_INFO_API = "http://localhost:3001/api/getInfo"
...

    getInfo(url) {
        return axios.get(GET_STEAM_API, {
            params: {
                url: url
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72577752/16462950. It describes how to call an external API from your express server.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by adding a callback to the getRest function:

```
app.get('/api/getInfo/', (req,res) => {
    const info = req.query.url;
    getRest(info, (error, response, body) => {
        res.send(JSON.parse(body));   
    });  
})

function getRest(url, callback) {
Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    callback(error, respose, body);
})
}
```